# Stop IE from automatically updating

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-update, internet-explorer-8

In my work, due to the fact I need to maintain older equipment, I need to keep IE8 and Java 1.6 (Java 6), I use Firefox or Chrome for everything other than older equipment, and this has never been a problem until I changed employers and got a new laptop. Now, every day a new version of IE gets installed... it is usually 11 but sometimes 9 or 10 and I have to uninstall it and go back to IE8.

Previously I would just hide the updates for IE in Windows update and it was never an issue, but doing that now does not seem to stop the update. I have also made these changes in my registry:

Registry Key:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Setup\11.0 (and the appropriate values in 9.0 and 10.0)

Type: REG_SZ
Name: DoNotAllowIE11 
Data value: 1

Type: REG_SZ
Name: DoNotOfferIE11AU
Data value: 1

I have also tried to completely disable the Windows Update service, but that seems to turn itself on daily as well.

I am using Windows 7 SP1 Professional 64-bit.

Help... I just want to keep IE8 and Java 6... Is that too much to ask?

Comment: Talk to your IT Administrator, it sounds like, your problem is that they are pushing updates to you.

Comment: Aye. Updates are very sensible **in most cases**. If you really need ancient software for work then you have a good business case to take to them. Either they will change the policies so that your laptop does not update, or they will offer an other solution (e.g. a Vm with the ancient software well secured from the rest of the network).

Comment: I have emailed our help desk, they say they are not forcing any updates and suggested the above registry keys. I have emailed them again but have not received a response as of yet.

Comment: @Hennes The virtual machine idea is actually a good one, I use Win XP VM in Win 7 for other things, I could use it for this as well as I really only need to use IE8 a couple times a month on average. If I cannot find a solution, this may be the best "answer". :/

Comment: I hate to break it to you.  The fact the updates keep being turned on indicate you are at the whims of a group policy.

Comment: I agree with Ramhound, everything you describe points to them pushing domain-level group polices on you to control your updates.  Use `gpresult` to prove if they are forcing polices on you or not.

Comment: I used gpresult /H report.html but what am I looking for? I don't see anything regarding updates in the result...

Comment: Just got an email from the help desk, I was instructed to remove Continuum ITSupport247 and report back in a few days if it doesn't fix my issue. Looks like they were pushing updates.

Comment: And that's why questions about office/work computers (that you don't fully control) are off-topic for SU. :)

Answer (score 0):

Open IE, go to `Help` and `About Internet Explorer`. Uncheck the `Install new versions automatically`.

[image]

*Note: I know this shows IE 11, but I don't have 8. It should be the same.*

Comment: In IE8 there is no check box for this, and when one of the higher versions is loaded the box is unchecked.

Comment: Sorry. Exactly why I made the note at the bottom. 9 must be where they added it. I'm going to leave the answer in case it will help someone else who is using newer than 8.

Comment: I'm using IE 11 and there isn't that option availible. :/. I'm trying to preserve at least one browser that will run adobe flash after 2020, so welp.